# package javafx does not exist for sample "mavenproject" netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am trying to run the "mavenproject1" file created by doing a "File::new project" and selecting "maven" then "JavaFX Application".

I am using the latest and greatest.  I have Java JDK 1.7.0_45 which I installed separately that is configured to build the project.  I have Netbeans 7.4 (Build 201310111528) with MAVEN 3 built in.  JavaFX is bundled with the JDK 1.7.0_45.

I can make the project execute, but my source files get an error indicating that the JavaFX package does not exist.  I added the following to my pom.xlm file which allows Maven to build and execute the source files even though the NB editor cannot find the JavaFX packages:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

How can I get the NB editor to recognize the JavaFX packages?

Comment: which os you are on ? and are you sure the file exists at path? and are you able to build it externally from terminal ?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.  The file exists at the path specified in the System Path for Java 7.  I can build it externally from the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, I advise using [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) as:

- JavaFX is on the default Java classpath in Java 8 but not in Java 7.
- As JavaFX is on the default Java 8 classpath, you don't need a system path dependency on jfxrt.jar in your maven project.
- As JavaFX is on the default Java 8 classpath NetBeans 7.4 should recognize JavaFX packages with no extra configuration.

You may also want to consider using the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin).

Comment: When I used Java 8 the problem went away.  I removed that dependency code from the pom.xml and it still built and ran.