# package does not exist javaFX with maven intel IDEA

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am developing an app, which uses Maven and JavaFX.
Until I added Maven dependencies, and Maven pom.xml, everything worked perfectly fine, but afterwards all the JavaFX packages became unrecognized. I tried pretty much everything, but nothing gave me the desired outcome.

As far as I can see I have everything in project structure correctly set up.

Here's a picture of problem:
[image]

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577995/package-javafx-does-not-exist-for-sample-mavenproject-netbeans-7-4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015731/javafx-project-doesnt-compile-with-maven)?

Comment: @user1 both links are for JavaFX with Java7 (and the most helpful answer is: use Java8). But this question is about Java10.

Comment: @devpuh there seems to be a few issues with java 9+ and javafx maven, for example check [this](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/287) issue, it seems we need to wait a while for things to work out